# Undefined Variable 'Comments' in Compact Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting 'undefined offset 1' error. It does returns everything I need -> the posts and the comments in the category. However, I believe the 'Undefined Offset 1' problem is probably due to some post which have no replies to them?? -> thus, help.

I have
1. Category Model
2. Post Model
3. Comment Model

This is the show function in my Category Model

```
  public function show($id)
    {

        $category = Category::with('posts.comments')->find($id);


        return view('categories.show', compact('category'));
    }
```

I have made relation for 'Category hasMany Posts' -> 'Post hasMany Comments'.

Comment: Variable scope problem, and why don't u use `with`

Comment: Recommend to use `Category::with('posts.comments')->find($id)`, your post and these answers all have n+1 query problem that will make your page load slowly.

Comment: Thank you. I am currently using your recommended answer. Heard of the n+1 problem but haven't really look into it yet as I am still a beginner in Laravel and PHP but will keep working on it. And I got another question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $comments = []; // Empty array to initialize the variable. This variable will be filled once the foreach statement is ran.
    $category = Category::find($id);
    if($category !== null) {
        $posts = $category->posts;

        foreach($posts as $post) {

            $comments = $post->comments;
        }

    }
    return view('categories.show', compact('posts', 'category', 'comments'));
}
```

Alternative method

```php
public function show(Category $category) //same as... public function show($id)
{
    return view('categories.show', compact('category'));
    /*
    Render this content in the view.
    @foreach($category->posts as $post)
      {{-- Display Post Content --}}
      @foreach($post->comments as $comment)
        {{-- Display Comment Content --}}
      @endforeach
    @endforeach
    */
}
```

Comment: Creating an empty array works. Thank you. I didn't even thought of that. facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

You are creating `$comments` variable inside `foreach` loop that make it's **scope locally** and will not be available outside `foreach`

To resolved this error you  need to define your `comments` variable inside your function so that it is available in your function

```
public function show($id)
        {
            $comments = [];  // define it here
            $category = Category::find($id);
            if($category !== null) {
                $posts = $category->posts;

                foreach($posts as $post) {

                    $comments = $post->comments;
                }

            }

                return view('categories.show', compact('posts', 'category','comments'));
            }
```

Comment: This is simply **incorrect**. `foreach` loops do not declare a variable scope. Variables declared inside a `foreach` loop are available outside of the loop.  You can verify it [here](https://3v4l.org/Z3Ps2), for example.